# Calling dll in python 3 with LPSTR

Tags: python-3.x, dll, ctypes, lpstr

I have a `.dll` named `my.dll`, with 4 functions, called in python 3.5 using:
    `myDLL = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(Path:\to\my.dll)`

My problem is calling a function that has `LPSTR`:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "newheader.h"    
double  _stdcall pain_function(double arg1, double arg2, LPSTR arg_string_with_spaces)
```

the other 3 calls to `my.dll` work fine.

Below is the code I tried for the `pain_function`:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes

# Load dll
myDLL = ctypes.WinDLL(Path:\to\my.dll)

# Call function 
pain_function = myDLL.pain_function

# Typecast the arguments
pain_function.argtypes = [ctypes.c_double, ctypes.c_double, wintypes.LPSTR]

# Typecast the return
pain_function.restype = ctypes.c_double


pain_return = pain_function(arg1, arg2, some_string)
```

`pain_return` returns some nonsensical number.  I tried some variations, mostly along the lines of:

```
some_string = ctypes.create_string_buffer(b' ' * 200)
```

I have looked here among other places:

1. [python-ctypes-prototype-with-lpcstr-out-parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896633/python-ctypes-prototype-with-lpcstr-out-parameter)
2. [Using String Parameters in DLL Function Calls](https://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/75417/?FullScreen=1&ShowTree=0)

What is this correct way to pass the string of 200 spaces to the dll?

Thank you in advance

Comment: `LPSTR` is an alias of `c_char_p`. If you prefer, you can use `from ctypes import wintypes; wintypes.LPSTR`. Since it's not `LPCSTR` (a constant string),  we should assume the function modifies the buffer, so you are correct to use `create_string_buffer`. There's no need to `encode` the value. Just use a `bytes` literal, e.g. `e = create_string_buffer(b' ' * 200)`. If you do encode the value, use the `'mbcs'` encoding instead of hard coding codepage 1252.

Comment: As to the nonsensical number, you didn't show the complete prototype. If `pain_function` has a `void` return value, set `pain_function.restype = None`. If it has a `double` return value, set `pain_function.restype = c_double`. And so on.

Comment: @eryksun Thanks! ... I guess there were two issues with the code (1) `restype` which I fixed (2) this `LPSTR` so now my argtype looks like this: `pain_function=[`ctypes.c_double, ctypes.c_double, wintypes.LPSTR]`    however - now it just returning a double, what else is missing?

Comment: If it's writing to `e`, check `e.value` to get the value as a null-terminated string. To get the whole array, use either `e.raw` or `e[:]`.

Comment: @eryksun what do you mean by  'writing to e.value'? I edited the question using your suggestions

Comment: I didn't say "writing to e.value". You're passing a 200 byte buffer to the function, I assume in order for the function to write a string or other data in the buffer. After you call the function, if it succeeds, the value as a null-terminated string (i.e. the bytes up to the first `NUL` byte) is `some_string.value` and the whole 200-byte array as a string is `some_string[:]` or `some_string.raw`. As to whether the function succeeds, please update your question to include the complete function prototype from the header, including the return type.

Comment: @eryksun Thanks.  You answered my question: `restype` and `wintype.LPSTR`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You indicated the prototype was:

```
double  _stdcall pain_function(double arg1, double arg2, LPSTR arg_string_with_spaces)
```

but using:

```
myDLL = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(Path:\to\my.dll)
```

It should be, for `__stdcall` calling convention:

```
myDLL = ctypes.WinDLL('Path:\to\my.dll')
```

Comment: Probably Itay is using 64-bit Python, on which it doesn't make a difference. But it's still better to use `WinDLL` to support 32-bit Python.

Comment: That is correct I am using  64-bit-Python.  And funny enough when I was trying to figure out the issue, I tried both and it did not make a difference.  That being said - I am incorporating the suggestions.

Comment: @ItayLivni, it does matter in 32-bit Python. In x86 `stdcall` (i.e. `WinDLL`), the callee cleans up the stack when returning, which is why you don't see this convention used with C variadic functions such as `printf`. ctypes checks for this in case a `stdcall` function is mistakenly called as `cdecl` (i.e. `CDLL`). In this case an exception should be raised such as "ValueError: Procedure called with not enough arguments (N bytes missing) or wrong calling convention", where N is the number of bytes the callee cleaned from the stack.